# is it possible to log un-encypted assertions in saml

Tags: saml

Our system logs assertions before we encrypt them using PROTOCOL_MESSAGE, but for some SP's doesn't encryption and there is no logging. Is there a way to log SAML assertions even when we are not encrypting.